# SICP exercise 1.37: My iterative solution got the right answer but got wrong in 1.38

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, sicp

My iterative solution to SICP 1.37 is

```
(define (con-frac n d k)
  (define (iter i result)
    (if (= 1 i)
        result
        (iter (- i 1) (/ (n i) (+ (d i) result)))))
  (iter k (/ (n k) (d k))))

(con-frac (lambda (i) 1.0) (lambda (i) 1.0) 11)

(define (euler-d i)
  (if (= 2 (remainder i 3))
      (* (/ 2 3) (+ i 1))
      1))

(define (e)
  (+ 2 (con-frac (lambda (i) 1.0) euler-d 9)))

(e)
```

It returns:

> ```
> Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.2.1 [3m].
> Language: SICP (PLaneT 1.17); memory limit: 128 MB.
> 0.6180555555555556
> 2.39221140472879
> ```

It should be return:

> ```
> Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.2.1 [3m].
> Language: SICP (PLaneT 1.17); memory limit: 128 MB.
> 0.6180555555555556
> 2.718283582089552
> ```

I don't know what's wrong with my solution.

Comment: Consider using float in your euler-d function `(if () (/ 2.0 3.0) ... 1.0)` Some implementation of '/ could return a truncate integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are off by one in the `iter`.

In

```
  (define (iter i result)
    (if (= 1 i)
        result
        (iter (- i 1) (/ (n i) (+ (d i) result)))))
```

change `(= 1 i)` to `(= 0 i`.

```
  (define (iter i result)
    (if (= 0 i)
        result
        (iter (- i 1) (/ (n i) (+ (d i) result)))))
```

The test using `phi` doesn't catch this since all numerators and denominators are equal.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed in @soegaard's answer, there's a simple [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in your code. Just replace this line:

```
(if (= 1 i)
```

With this one - it's a bit more idiomatic than asking if `(= 0 i)`:

```
(if (zero? i)
```

... And that's all!